# 'getComputedStyle' does not recognize element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, getcomputedstyle

In my React app, I'm trying to use `getComputedStyle` and `getPropertyValue` for my component, but it fails to execute because it doesn't seem to recognize my element. I get `TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element`

```
const [dashboardToggle, setDashboardToggle] = useState(false);

  const boardElement = document.getElementsByClassName("dashboard");
  const boardPosition = window
    .getComputedStyle(boardElement[0])
    .getPropertyValue("position");
    

  console.log("this" + boardElement);
  console.log("this" + boardPosition);

return (<div className="App"><AnimatePresence>
        {dashboardToggle && (
          <Dashboard
            className="dashboard"
            dashboardToggle={dashboardToggle}
          ></Dashboard>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>)
    </div>
```

When I console log `boardElement`, I get `[object HTMLCollection]`. I assume `boardElement[0]` should be an element param for `getComputedStyle`.

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: *"When I console log `boardElement`, I get `[object HTMLCollection]`. I assume `boardElement[0]` should be an element param for `getComputedStyle`."* It would be **if** there were any entries in the collection, but it would appear there aren't, so `boardElement[0]` is `undefined`, which isn't an element. It looks like you're looking for the element before it exists (because it hasn't been rendered yet).

Comment: As a side note, though, rather than querying the DOM to access that element, use a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). You also need to wrap the code that uses the element in a callback (`useEffect` or `useLayoutEffect`). (You also have a syntax error -- the `</div>` at the end should be *before* the closing `)`.)

Comment: [Here's an example](https://pastebin.com/S453XhrE) of that code using `useEffect` and a ref.